# Convert asp.net website solution to visual web part

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a small website written in asp.net c#. It consists of 7 pages or less, connected to a database and references a class library. How to convert it to a visual web part in sharepoint 2013? my colleague advised me of copying the codes from the website solution to a visual web part solution. The question is, is his suggestion feasible? are there any other ways of doing it besides iframes and my colleague's suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Your options depends on if your solution will live in a Publishing Portal or not. The most generic way would probably be to use a visual webpart and host it there. If you would like a more comparable version of this from your current solution you can build and deploy custom page layouts hosting your code.